# how to rank/group 3 rows each in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 6 records, and need to get the results in the format below, grouping them into 3 rows each.

Input table:

```
id     Value
-------------
1       abcd
2       defgh
3       ijkl
4       mnop
5       qrst
6       uvwx
```

Output format needed:

```
Rank   id     Value
--------------------
1       1     abcd
1       2     defgh
1       3     ijkl
2       4     mnop
2       5     qrst
2       6     uvwx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NTILE() here.

```
SELECT NTILE(2) OVER(ORDER BY id),id FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Think of it as buckets, NTILE(2) will make 2 buckets, half the rows will have the value 1 and the other half the value 2

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by (id - 1)/3) as grp, id, value
from t;
```

This assumes, as in your sample data, that `id` starts at 1 and increases with no gaps.

If that is not true, then an alternative is:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by seqnum/3) as grp, id, value
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     );
```